# Django Authenticiation outside of username/password

Tags: python, django, backend

Is there any way to authenticate with another object other than username/password?

I have a dashboard where I'd like to continue to use username/password auth, however that's not suitable for an API. How can one implement an API key that can also log you in?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey. Check token authentication from django rest framework https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication or simple jwt : https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate token for a user and use that token for authentication along with the apis.

You can see more details [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)